# Simply fputs() example returns EOF

Tags: c, fputs

This simple program, gives me troubles in fgets(), returning EOF, that is an error value for fgets()
I don't understand where is the problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

FILE* openFile(const char* path)
{
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(path, "r");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        perror(path);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return file;
}


int main()
{
    FILE* file;
    char stringVector[6] = "hello";
    file = openFile("/home/user/workspace/fputs/src/testo.txt");

    if(fputs(&stringVector[0], file) == EOF)
    {
        printf("error in fputs");
        fclose(file);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's errno set to?  Per the fputs() documentation, when EOF is returned, the value errno will be set with a code indicative of specifics.

Comment: ... and `perror` will print the error for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are opening the file for reading, yet trying to write data to it? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

In 'openFile()', you open the file with 'r', but 'fputs' wants to 'w' the file.

Answer (score 1):

Hm: &stringVector[0] ?

Which is exactly the same as doing : a = 1 - 1, why don't you do a = 0?

-> stringVector = &stringVector[0]